# NetSuite SOAP API: Populate PurchaseOrderList on VendorBill record retrieval

Tags: soap, netsuite, suitetalk

When using the NetSuite SOAP API I would like to retrieve the `purchaseOrderList` for a `VendorBill` record. The `purchaseOrderList` field is shown as a `RecordRefList` on [this docs page](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2020_1/schema/record/vendorbill.html), however that field doesn't populate on responses when performing a `get` to retrieve a `vendorBill` based on the `internalId`.

I've tried setting the `bodyFieldsOnly` header to false, hoping this would cause it to return all related fields, however this doesn't change the response.

Does anyone know how to force a `RecordRefList` field type to populate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching through the docs online it seems that the `purchaseOrderList` property on the Vendor Bill is only used when updating the bill to associate it with Purchase Orders, it doesn't look like the property can be returned when retrieving Vendor Bill records. See [this docs page](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_N3687718.html) under the 'Linking Purchase Orders to a Vendor Bill' section.

In order to retrieve the PO numbers associated with a Vendor Bills items and expenses I am retrieving them from the `itemList` and `expenseList` properties which are present on the Vendor Bill. If anyone knows of another way please feel free to comment or edit.

Comment: Hi @Issac, can you let me know how are you pulling itemList and expenseList properties in the Vendor Bill?